Is it possible to edit the "edit" screen of Service Appointment in the Field Service Mobile App?
Recently I've implemented Field Service Flow to send an error if there's a change on an specific status of Service Appointment and there's no service report associated to it. It worked when the user tries to change the status using the actions, but if they change the status using the edit tab, it's possible to go ahead without this validation.
I need to know if its possible to edit the "edit" screen of Service Appointment in the Field Service Mobile App, so I can try to remove the status field from the edit page. Or if anyone has a better idea to fix this, any help would be appreciated!
